# Equivalent for .HasOptional in Entity Framework Core 1 (EF7)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Consider two classes.

```
public class File
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Message_Id { get; set; }

    internal Message Message { get; set; }
}

public class Message 
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }       
}
```

In EF6, for N : 1..0 relation there was this fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.Message ).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.Message_Id);
```

What is equivalent in Entiity Framework Core 1?

Thank you

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You will not find an equivalent method in EF 7. By convention, a property whose CLR type can contain `null` will be configured as optional. So what decide if the relationship is optional or not is if the FK property is [nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) or not respectively.

In summary, due to your `Message_Id`  FK property is `string`, it already  accepts `null` value, so if you use the following Fluent Api configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Message)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.Message_Id)
```

EF will configure your relationship as optional (or N : 0..1 as requested).

In case of your FK property is value type like `int`, you should declare it as nullable (`int?`).

Also I noticed now you have a navigation property with `internal` access modifier. You should always declare your entity properties as `public`.

Comment: Just to add an observation: EF will also configure the relationship as required given a `[Required]` annotation on the property, even if the type itself is nullable.

Comment: Don't think this is true. EF6 AND EF Core are both capable of representing 1 : 0..1 relationships as EntityA.PK is foreign key to EntityB.PK

Comment: @shannon Take a look in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) and show me in fluent api how to do an `HasOptional` without do what I explain in my answer

Comment: @shannon, also I never said is not capable of do it. What I show is how to do it in EF Core, because HasOptional method was deprecated. But definitely is possible if the FK property is nullable

Comment: @octavioccl: You are correct, I misread the requirement as "1 : 0..1" (as can be seen in my comment above), when it is clearly stated as "N : 0..1". I'll remove the downvote (will require edit to permit). I would recommend a less personal reaction in the future; I might have been quicker to spot the error was mine if our interaction was less emotional.

Comment: My apologies for that. I will take your advice in the future

Comment: `You should always declare your entity properties as public.` This is incorrect. If you have something you don't want exposed outside of your class, you can declare it as `protected internal` so that Entity Framework can still work with the property, but it can't be accessed by anything else.

Comment: Working on EF core after a long time and was trying to sort this out. That nullable ef really helped

Comment: If your child model doesn't have a foreign key property, use ".IsRequired(bool)" which defaults to true.

Comment: If your child model doesn't have a foreign key property, the foreign key field in the database is nullable by default.

Comment: Does HasOne() is the equivalent for HasOptional()?

Comment: @KarthicG only if property is nullable

Comment: I found that using `int?` didn't work for me (Net 6.0, EF Core 7.0) as it always created a non-nullable field despite the use of a nullable int. I had to use `builder.Property(p => p.FieldName).IsRequired(false)` when configuring the entity in order to force it. Then it worked.

Answer (score 17):

To add to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35562728/1543677), if your property can't be configured as nullable (for example, if you are dealing with a split-table scenario, where the property is the primary key), adding `IsRequired(false)`, will make the join optional (LEFT).

Like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
    .HasOne(s => s.Message)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.Message_Id)
    .IsRequired(false)
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed this so that I could use a Primary Key as a Foreign Key for a 0..1 relationship. I couldn't make the primary key nullable so this was the solution I needed.

Comment: Thank you. This should be the answer since it is simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 12):

In EF Core you can use two ways for relating two tables:

- Inside `OnModelCreating`:

  ```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);            

      modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
                  .HasOne(c => c.Message)
                  .WithOne()
                  .HasForeignKey(c => c.MessageId)                           
  }
  ```
- Create new class `FileConfiguration` and calling it inside `OnModelCreating`:

  ```
  public class FileConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<File>
  {
      public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<File> builder)
      {           
          builder.ToTable("File");            

          // Id
          builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
          builder.Property(c => c.Id)
                 .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

          // Message
          builder.HasOne(c => c.Message)
                 .WithOne(c => c.File)
                 .HasForeignKey<Message>(c => c.MessageId)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
      }
  }
  ```

  and inside OnModelCreating put below codes:

  ```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new FileConfiguration());                                       
  }
  ```

Comment: what can i do for self reference.