# Defining Foreign Key Relationships in EF / MVC6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have extend the `ApplicationUser` class in the template models to include an *optional* Company:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Guid? CompanyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

And in the 'Company' class I've included a collection of `ApplicationUsers`:

```
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public Guid? CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
```

Do I also need to specify the relation in the `ModelBuilder` for the `ApplicationdbContext`? or should Code-First handle this for me?

I ask because when I grab `_context.Users.ToList()` in a controller `Company` is always `null`, even if `CompanyID` is populated for the `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: That has worked. Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1

Answer (score 1):

Change Model To It:

```
[Required]
[Key]
public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
```

And Config MolderBinder For ApplicationUser To this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasOptional(row => row.Company ).WithMany().HasForeignKey(row => row.CompanyID ).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: No `HasOptional` available - what's the namespace?

Comment: System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration

Comment: Not yet! That namespace doesn't seem to be available - is it ready for DNX 5?

Comment: Yes , The following references are available? EntityFramework , System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations , System.Core , System.Data

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/35562483/2591770 - I think `HasOptional` has been removed from EF7 / Core