# How to configure this one-to-zero-or-one relationship?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I know there are some answered questions on SO about 1:0..1-relationships. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240362/one-to-one-optional-relationship-using-entity-framework-fluent-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562483/equivalent-for-hasoptional-in-entity-framework-core-1-ef7), but don't think they apply to my question.

I have these three (simplified) models in a CMS-system.

```
public class FrontPageItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemType { get; set; } // 1 = Article, 2 = WebPage, etc...

    public int? ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }

    public int? WebPageId { get; set; }
    public WebPage WebPage { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Preamble { get; set; }
    public string MainText { get; set; }

    public int? FrontPageItemId { get; set; }
    public FrontPageItem FrontPageItem { get; set; }
}

public class WebPage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int? FrontPageItemId { get; set; }
    public FrontPageItem FrontPageItem { get; set; }
}
```

The relationships between a `FrontPageItem` and each of the different element types are one-to-zero-or-one. An element can exist without being added as a `FrontPageItem`, meaning that a `FrontPageItem` has a relationship to just one element, either an `Article` or a `WebPage`.

In an attempt to configure the relationships, I have added this bit of code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
        .HasOne(p => p.FrontPageItem)
        .WithOne(i => i.Article)
        .HasForeignKey<FrontPageItem>(b => b.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<WebPage>()
        .HasOne(p => p.FrontPageItem)
        .WithOne(i => i.WebPage)
        .HasForeignKey<FrontPageItem>(b => b.Id);
}
```

But I don't think it's correct. I haven't made the CRUD-views for `FrontPageItem` yet, but if I try to add items directly in the SQL Server Object Explorer in VS, I have to enter a value for the PK.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So FrontPageItem must have an Article and a Webpage or only one of them?

Comment: @Nikolaus Only one of them.

Comment: Did the answer fit your needs?

Comment: @Nikolaus I don't know yet. I will look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said:

> The relationships between a `FrontPageItem` and each of the different element types are `one-to-zero-or-one`. An element can exist without being added as a `FrontPageItem`, meaning that a `FrontPageItem` has a relationship to just one element, either an `Article` or a `WebPage`.

Then remove `ArticleId` and `WebPageId` from `FrontPageItem` as EF core support `one-to-one-or-zero` association without foreign key in principle table:

```
public class FrontPageItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemType { get; set; } // 1 = Article, 2 = WebPage, etc...

    public Article Article { get; set; }
    public WebPage WebPage { get; set; }
}
```

Then the **Fleunt API** configuration for `Article` and `WebPage` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
        .HasOne(a => a.FrontPageItem)
        .WithOne(f => f.Article)
        .HasForeignKey<Article>(a => a.FrontPageItemId); // <-- Here it is

    modelBuilder.Entity<WebPage>()
        .HasOne(wp => wp.FrontPageItem)
        .WithOne(f => f.WebPage)
        .HasForeignKey<WebPage>(wp => wp.FrontPageItemId); // <--Here it is
}
```

Comment: You've messed up the dependent and principal roles - it should be exactly the opposite of what you are doing. The way it is now the answer is simply wrong and leads OP in a wrong direction.

Comment: You can read it too, and also their [follow up issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55942221/why-arent-related-entities-loaded-on-include) caused by your answer. Even just from the quoted part you've mentioned, it's pretty obvious that `Article` and `WebPage` are principals, and `FrontPageItem` is the dependent (referencing one of them).

Comment: Okay! If it really then OP asked the question wrongly here. Moreover read the OP‘s second question where he has described the relation wrongly!

Comment: I agree, but that's why we are here :) And note that 1:0..1 doesn't define who is the principal. Say we have `A` and `B`. Looking from `A` to `B` it's 1 A to 0..1 B. But looking from B, it's also 1 B to 0..1 As you can see, all it says is that each entity can exist separately w/o the other. So with one-to-one relationships, the first thing to be figured out is who is the principal, and second is the FK in the dependent required or not. And that's all. All other is just a few fluent API calls.

Comment: Yes! You are absolutely correct! He confused us about the what actual relationship is! Who is the principle or who is the dependent!

Comment: @TanvirArjel I can assure you - I am confused myself. ;)