# Zero-to-many relationship, or something else? Using FluentAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have an "Item" table defined as such:

```
item_id
Name
Description
itemseries_id
itemtype_id
itemcondition_id
```

And then I have "ItemForSale" table:

```
itemforsale_id
item_id
price
date_added
```

Entities:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ItemSeriesId { get; set; }
    public ItemSeries ItemSeries { get; set; }

    public int ItemConditionId { get; set; }
    public ItemCondition ItemCondition { get; set; }

    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
    public ItemType ItemType { get; set; }

    public List<ItemTag> ItemTags { get; set; }
    public List<ItemImage> ItemImages { get; set; }
    public List<ItemPurchase> ItemPurchases { get; set; }
    public List<ItemSale> ItemSales { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ItemForSale
{
    public int ItemForSaleId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

How would I use the FluentAPI between these? I know I could add a reference to ItemForSale inside the Item entity class, but it doesn't make sense to me. So far I have mapped all of my One-to-one and many-to-many relationships, but the relationship between Item and ItemForSale is just confusing me.

Note: I am distinguishing between items that have been sold as a "Sale" or "ItemSale" and an item up for sale with no buyer as "ItemForSale"

Comment: Hey @alioc, Welcome to Stack Overflow! As far as I could understand, you can just map your relationship as if it would be a "one-to-many" relationship, like in this documentation page here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: This can also help you: I don't think it qualifies this question to be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562483/equivalent-for-hasoptional-in-entity-framework-core-1-ef7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [EF Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key), you can do something like this:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemSale> ItemSales { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemSale>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Item)
            .WithMany(b => b.ItemSales)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ItemId)
            .IsRequired(false);
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<ItemSale> ItemSales { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSale
{
    public int ItemSaleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }
    
    // note that the reference id is nullable
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
}
```

And then, mark the property `ItemId` in your model class as `int?`. While on EF 6, we had the `HasOptional` configuration option, but on EF Core, if the reference property can be nullable, it assumes the property starts from 0, like `0..N`. I think that even the `IsRequired(false)` is not needed in this context as well, but here it goes.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about the relationship as a one-to-many, but that's exactly what it is.

Comment: You're welcome, @alioc. Please note that I edited the code to include the nullable reference.