# Replace HasOptional() using Roslyn c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have implemented the project of EntityFramework 6 into EntityFramework Core 3.1. I am new to Roslyn API.

**Sample.cs**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
                    .HasOptional(c => c.Spouse)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(c => c.SpouseId);
 }
```

has to become

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
                    .HasOne(c => c.Spouse)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(c => c.SpouseId);
 }
```

Kindly someone help me that how to do that in Roslyn

Comment: This seems like something that could be done with find-and-replace, or at least find-all; can you clarify why you are trying to use Roslyn here? There may well
 be a reason - but it isn't an obvious direction.

Comment: how to find and replace in C# and roslyn is the my requirement.thats why. One more thing do you know what is the equivalent part of HasOptional() in EFCore

Comment: That's like saying "putting screws in with a hammer is my requirement, that's why".

Comment: ha ha...thanks.what is the equivalent part of HasOptional()?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562483/equivalent-for-hasoptional-in-entity-framework-core-1-ef7

Comment: yes, i referred that link already, they suggested as HasIndex() replacement. is it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226881/discussion-between-karthic-g-and-marc-gravell).