# INSERT statement conflicted with FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This error occurs when adding new category with no parent. I have tried similar question's answers but no result.

Model

```
public class Category
{
    [Column("CategoryId")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category name is a required field.")]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Minimum length for the Name is 1 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }

}
```

Request

```
public class CategoryCreationDto
{
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Repository

```
public void Create(T entity) => RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Add(entity); 
public void CreateCategory(Category category) => Create(category);
```

Controller

```
 Category categoryEntity = _mapper.Map<Category>(category);
        _repository.Category.CreateCategory(categoryEntity);
        await _repository.SaveAsync();
```

Table generated by entity framework

[image: Table generated by entity framework]

Comment: BTW, your database design doesn't prevent reference-cycles.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Can't test, but changing the attribute to `[ForeignKey("Parent")]` on the same property _or_ moving the attribute as is to the Parent property would make more sense to me.

Comment: The code you show is largely a black box. We don't see what's in `category`/`categoryEntity`.

Comment: Where are you assigning a unique value to `CategoryId`?

Answer (score 2):

It's correlated with your entity relations.

Look at this example:

[image]

There is issue - when one entity can't exist with another.
You can't have **Order** without **Customer** and **Product**.

You need to first INSERT record for **Customer* and **Product** to add **Product**.

---

In your specific case:

First add those to db:

```
 public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
```

to add **Category**.

---

For optional foreign key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.Parent)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentId);
```

Comment: I need to add Category without a parent. Parent property  is optional

Comment: Ok - then when mapping relationship - there is need to add optional foreign key(edited answer)

Comment: Just for the record  - ef core ModelBuilder doesn't have .HasOptional

Comment: It's depend on version -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562483/equivalent-for-hasoptional-in-entity-framework-core-1-ef7

Comment: @PiotrŻak EF core was called EF7

Answer (score 1):

You will  have to add fluent apis (repeat db migration after this)

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
  modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Parent)
            .WithMany(m => m.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId);

 OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
 }
```

I am sorry but since you didn't post what is your mapper doing and what is inside of category,  I will post the whole code for the test (it was tested in VS)

```
        var categoryEntity = new Category {Id=new Guid(), Name="CategoryName"};
        context.Set<Category>().Add(categoryEntity ); 
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```