# Entity Framework Core: How should I configure a non-required composite foreign key to not cascade on delete?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have two tables: `Superhero` and `Universe`.

`Superhero` has a composite primary key, since Loki's introduced us to variants, modeled in EF Core like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Superhero>()
    .HasKey(o => new { o.Id, o.UniverseId });
```

Some superheroes have hero parents, so I need `Superhero` to have a self-referencing foreign key, which is not required:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Superhero>()
        .HasOne(o => o.ParentHero)
        .WithMany(o => o.ChildHeroes)
        .HasForeignKey(o => new { o.ParentId, o.UniverseId })
        .IsRequired(false);
```

I don't want cascade on delete for this relationship; instead, I'd like to set the children's `ParentId` column to `null`, while the `UniverseId` column remains unchanged. I thought I could accomplish this by using the `DeleteBehavior.SetNull` option:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Superhero>()
            .HasOne(o => o.ParentHero)
            .WithMany(o => o.ChildHeroes)
            .HasForeignKey(o => new { o.ParentId, o.UniverseId })
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
            .IsRequired(false)
            ;
```

But that doesn't work as I expected. When I remove the parent hero, like so:

```
DbContext.Superhero.Remove(parentHero);
```

I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
> The association between entity types 'Universe' and 'Superhero' has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.  Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values.

Is there any way I can get around this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent for .HasOptional in Entity Framework Core 1 (EF7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562483/equivalent-for-hasoptional-in-entity-framework-core-1-ef7)

Comment: I don't think so, but thanks! The only difference from my original configuration is the `IsRequired` call, but removing that doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: Not possible, because of the relational databases FK constraint rules - all composite FK columns must be null or not null. There is nothing EF Core can do as it is database restriction.

Comment: I don't think that's right. In SQL, I can create an optional foreign key that references two columns, one nullable and the other non-nullable.